# How to get data from other php scripts

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 files, one is used to view the data in the mysql database, and list it on a table:

```
if($_POST['general'] == 'ADDRESS'){
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE ADDRESS='$saddress'");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>IDNO</th>
<th>ADDRESS</th>
<th>LASTNAME</th>
<th>FIRSTNAME</th>
<th>VIEW</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['IDNO'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ADDRESS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=" . $row['IDNO'] . "'>view</a></td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
}
```

And this one is the update.php which I am working on, I just want to be able to see the data that corresponds to the one the record that I clicked on the first one using the link "view".

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("school", $con);
 $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='?'");
?>



<tr>
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="3">*I D Number:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="idnum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $row["IDNO"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

But I do not know how do I link the two, in such a way that the corresponding data in here:

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=" . $row['IDNO'] . "'>view</a></td>";
```

would be reflected in here:

```
<td width="30"><input  name="idnum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $row["IDNO"]; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
```

Please give me an idea on how I can do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first php file, you specified that the url that users can click will look something like:

```
<a href="update.php?id=123"></a>
```

You can get the value of "id" in update.php by:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // $id will be 123
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding you right:

```
include("mysqlfile.php");
```

in the other file

but I'm not exactly clear on what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jamie for the include(); but I rather prefer require();

so:

```
<?php require("mysqlfile.php"); ?>
```

The difference is that if there's a problem with the required file, such as its not there, it'll stop the script completely after displaying an error, where an include will just display an error and then continue parsing the rest of it.

So for example, if you're including a script that handles additional sanitation, and it breaks or goes down, then the rest of the script would still run without the extra sanitation, thus making you vulnerable to SQL injection or other exploits.

However if you're REQUIRING a script that handles the additional sanitation, and it broke, the entire page would break and you'd be fine until you got the required script back up.